# first product they purchase and the next product they purchase will be sub of first product

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services

Hi All i having issue on this query, being stuck for 2 weeks, if possible anyone can help me with the solution will be great

My task is I want to get list of ID user what the

[image: first product they purchase and the next product they purchase will be sub of first product]

from the below sample table given (attach)

my objective is i want to get from the list of ID, the first product they purchase will determine which parent tier there are,

SO example ABC123 the first product is a thus ABC123 will be in parent a and all the upcoming product will be under a,

ABC123 should not be inside parent b,

below are the code that currently i did,

```
select date,ID,product, 'A_Parent' AS parent
from product_info where ID IN ( select ID from product_info where product='a') --parent a
UNION
select date,ID,product,'B_Parent' AS parent
from product_info where ID IN (select ID from product_info where product='b') -- parent b
```

Can someone please help me on how to tackle this issue.

Attach photo as sample table
1. Expected out
2. Sample table : product_info

Totally appreciate it

Comment: Better put the data as text so we can work with the data

Comment: @AfiqHilmi . . . AWS is a service provides that gives access to multiple different databases.  Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want the first product, use `first_value()`:

```
select pi.*,
       first_value(pi.product) over (partition by pi.id order by pi.date) as first_product
from product_info pi;
```